# Make data inside of a QLabel scale to fit it's height

Tags: c++, qt

I am displaying some data inside a **QLabel** as can be seen in the image below

[image]

The label is rectangular with dimensions of *100x100* pixels, and I display the data inside a *for loop* line by line as can be seen below

```
 for (int i = 0; i < winSize; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < winSize; j++)
        {            
            int val = val1[counter];

            label->setFont(m_labelFont);

            label->setText(label->text() + " " + QString::number(val));

            counter = counter + 1;
        }

        label->setText(this->text() + "\n");
    }
```

Those empty spaces above and below the data look kind of bad though, and I would like to somehow scale the lines so as the content to fit inside the label's height.

Is there a way of doing that?

Comment: How do you exactly fill the label? Did you try setting padding to 0?

Comment: @svlasov see edit. I didn't know I can mess with padding in a QLabel.

Comment: For example `label->setStyleSheet("padding: 0");`

Comment: I tested it but it did not solve the issue. The empty spaces remain. Even though at least I would expect the label to start the text from the top left corner.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using `line-height` CSS propery:

```
label->setFont(m_labelFont);
for (int i = 0; i < winSize; i++)
{
    QString line = "<p style=\"line-height:100\">";
    for (int j = 0; j < winSize; j++)
    {            
        int val = val1[counter];
        line += QString::number(val) + " ";
        counter = counter + 1;
    }
    line += "</p>";
    label->setText(label->text() + line);
}
```

Also, consider removing the contents margins of the layout that holds the label:

```
layout()->setContentsMargins(0, 0, 0, 0);
```

[image]

Comment: I did those exacts changes a moment ago, so we end up with a big empty space at the bottom. For the moment I am not sure that there is any option for line spacing in Qt. Temporarily I adjusted the height of QLabel to fit the contents and not the opposite.

Comment: Empty space at the bottom is due to the extra empty line.

Comment: There is a check for an empty line, it is just that the total text width is more than the text height. So in order to uniformly fit this text into a square label I will need to increase the empty space between a line and the next one. As an example your label is also not a square, that is how the text fits.

Comment: Embarrassing, I understood your question wrong in the beginning. So try with `line-height`. I updated the answer.

Comment: Are you kidding me, I tried line-height and it did not work correctly at the time, no idea if there was something else interfering. Thanks svlasov.

Answer (score 1):

You can define text formatting inside a QLabel using the following code:

```
QLabel* yourLabel = new QLabel();
yourLabel->setTextFormat(Qt::RichText);
yourLabel->setText(<your html formatted text>)
```

Have a look here http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/richtext-html-subset.html to get the subset of html's tags supported!

Comment: I did a few test but I am still not getting the desired result. I tried `label->setText(label->text() + " " + QString("<margin-bottom: 4px>%1").arg(tempVal));`
But this just displays a line on the middle of the label. No other lines are visible